# evaluate the improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left( \tan^2\left( \frac\pi4 + x \right) \right) \tan x\, dx
$$
I tried to solve this question by substitution and let $u=\tan x$ 
And then using integration by parts or substitution 
But I want another method to solve it

Comment: If you succeeded in evaluating it, why do you need a second solution?

Comment: @Chris OP may be looking for an easier method.

Comment: @projectilemotion  How can any answerer write an "easier method", when the asker has refused to include his/her own work.

Comment: @amWhy I was thinking exactly the same, there is a lack of context in the question. It would have been a lot better if the derivation was shown explicitly, and would have made it a lot easier for us to provide an easier method.

Comment: I have evaluated it by series by letting u= tanx then break the interval from (0,1) and from (1,inf) then using a series to represent the integral withous using integration by parts

Comment: @chris no need for your methods thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

** just a hint**

$$\int_0^\frac \pi 2=\int_0^\frac \pi 4+\int_\frac \pi 4^\frac \pi 2$$

$$\ln (\tan^2 (A ))=2\ln (|\tan (A)|) $$

$$\tan (x+\pi/4)=\frac {1+\tan (x)}{1-\tan (x)} $$

put $t=\tan (x) $

then by parts.